# File download fails in IE10 but works in chrome - HTTP 400 error

Tags: java, internet-explorer, tomcat, http-status-code-400, bad-request

We have a JAVA web application and recently we migrated to a new software. Earlier we used `WebSphere 7` as a application server but after migration we moved to `Tomcat 7`.
In regression testing we found a issue with PDF download on one of the web pages.

The page has 4 PDF file download link all of them pointing to same `struts action` class. But only two of them works in IE 10 (v-10.0.9200.16897) and other two fails with the "`Http 400 - Bad Request`" error. We tested the same page on Chrome browser and all pdf download link work fine.

The strange thing is if I copy the non-working download link and open it another tab then the download works just fine. But try to open it in current page and it fails.

Has anyone experienced this behavior? Or if you can help me to identify the issue it will be a great help.

Thanks,
Hanumant

Comment: Have you compared Chrome & IE's HTTP request headers in the browsers F12 network tool (or Fiddler)?

Comment: Yes I have compared the header and the request header is almost same. Even tried IE10's Browser and Document mode to change the version but didn't help.

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: The difference was in user-agent IE has Mozilla 4.0 whereas Chrome has Mozilla 5.0. But then I changed the Browser / Document mode and got the User Agent Mozilla 5.0 in IE but still didn't work.